# Disable Objective-C automatic property synthesis for a class?

Tags: objective-c, clang

I am writing a wrapper class that uses the dynamic runtime to forward messages to the wrapped object, using `forwardInvocation:`

However the type checker now complains that the methods aren't implemented on my wrapper class, which is generally a good thing.

So I thought I'd write some method declarations in the header of my wrapper to satisfy the type checker. Note that I just want the declarations, not the definitions.

However, when I copy over my `@property` directives, they are not just declared, but defined as well, and in this way they take precedence over the method forwarding, and so it breaks the forwarding.

So is there a way to declare a `@property` and not have it automatically synthesize getters and setters? I love this feature so I'd want to disable on a per class basis only, and leave it on for the rest of the project. A bit like `-fno-objc-arc`.

P.S. `clang -v` => `$ Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add

```
@dynamic yourProperty;
```

to the class implementation then no instance variables and no accessor functions will be
synthesized for that property.

Comment: Unfortunately this not generate a single warning about lack of accessor method and app will crashed on access to property.